# How to get the split view master part fram in iPad?

Tags: ios, objective-c, splitview

I want to get the view frame. Which is done by this line:

```
self.view.frame
```

but when I do this in iPad it is equal to the whole view. but I just want the master part of the split view.

Answer (score 0):

The frame of the master view controller in a split view can be accessed as

```
UIViewController* master = splitViewController.viewControllers[0];
CGRect frame = master.view.frame;
```